# Replace missing data with values from matching rows in another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, join, sqldf

I want to replace values of a variable.

This is my dB :

```
head(mydb)

ID   V1     V2     V3     V4 
1    value  value  0    0
2    value  value  0    0  
3    value  value  0    0
4    value  value  0    0  
5    value  value  0    0
6    value  value  0    0
```

`V3` and `V4` have **`0`** for all observations.

Then I created several dBs like below:

```
head(newdb)
ID   V3     V4 
2    5      4  
4    8      5  
6    9      6
```

I want to obtain something like this :

```
ID   V1     V2     V3     V4 
1    value  value  0    0
2    value  value  5    4  
3    value  value  0    0
4    value  value  8    5  
5    value  value  0    0
6    value  value  9    6
```

I tried with [sqldf](/questions/tagged/sqldf) to do it like this :

```
mydf <- sqldf('SELECT mydf.*, newdb.v3, newdb.v4              
               FROM mydf
               LEFT JOIN newdb 
               ON  mydf.ID = newdb.id')
```

The code I created works well and do its job; but the problem is that I'm inside a for loop, and for each of my `newDB` the `sql` code generates others `V3` and `V4` and attach it close the previous one creating something like this :

```
ID   V1     V2     V3   V4   V3   V4   V3  V4
1    value  value  0    0    1    5    0   0
2    value  value  5    4    0    0    0   0
3    value  value  0    0    0    0    7   8
4    value  value  8    5    0    0    0   0
5    value  value  0    0    2    2    0   0 
6    value  value  9    6    0    0    0   0
```

I've added another V3 and V4 columns for each iterations of my loop (in this case 3 iterations).

How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: add a suffix to the column.names

Comment: @Wimpel tbh not fond of your solution but just expanding it. OP later can use `rowsum` and `grepl` together to get the sum of `V3`s and `V4`s and create two final columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply match the IDs in two dataframes and replace them in the original one:

```
mydf[,c("V3","V4")] <- newdf[match(mydf$ID, newdf$ID),c("V3","V4")]

mydf
#   ID  V1    V2   V3 V4
# 1  1 value value NA NA
# 2  2 value value  5  4
# 3  3 value value NA NA
# 4  4 value value  8  5
# 5  5 value value NA NA
# 6  6 value value  9  6
```

Later you can replace `NA`s with `0`s.

***Update:***

Instead of doing a `for-loop` concatenate all the `newdf`s together and then run the code on that; look at the pseudo-code below:

```
newdf_concat <- rbind(newdf1, newdf2)

mydf[,c("V3","V4")] <- newdf_concat[match(mydf$ID, newdf_concat$ID),c("V3","V4")]
```

Comment: @IceCreamToucan I don't want to avoid `NA` as it actually carries some meaning. Later, if it is actually needed, you can get rid of them (I doubt that it cannot be avoided tho). Cheers.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan I understand. That's why I stated at the bottom that you later can replace them (which is the easiest task). But, as said above, it is not my personal preference and would recommend OP to avoid that. We may as well share some of our experience along with the code we provide. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you! It works greatly.

I've only a problem right now. 

I'm inside a for loop, and at each iteration using the match function replaces the values that there were before.

I would like to "overwrite" V3 and V4 at each step of my loop in order to fill it. Is it possible?

Comment: @ianux22 instead of using a for loop like that, append all the `newdf`s together and do it in one step; `newdf_concat <- rbind(newdf1, newdf2)` and then run my code on `mydf` and `newdf_concat`. That way it is also more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

You can do update joins quite easily with data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydb)
setDT(newdb)

mydb[newdb, on = 'ID', c('V3', 'V4') := .(i.V3, i.V4)]

mydb
#    ID    V1    V2 V3 V4
# 1:  1 value value  0  0
# 2:  2 value value  5  4
# 3:  3 value value  0  0
# 4:  4 value value  8  5
# 5:  5 value value  0  0
# 6:  6 value value  9  6
```

You can use `sqldf` too, but you have to use `coalesce` (same result as above)

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('
SELECT  mydb.ID
        , mydb.V1
        , mydb.V2
        , coalesce(newdb.v3, mydb.V3) as V3
        , coalesce(newdb.v4, mydb.V4) as V4
FROM    mydb
        LEFT JOIN newdb 
          using(id)
')
```

Data used:

```
mydb <- fread('
ID   V1     V2     V3     V4 
1    value  value  0    0
2    value  value  0    0  
3    value  value  0    0
4    value  value  0    0  
5    value  value  0    0
6    value  value  0    0  
')
newdb <- fread('
ID   V3     V4 
2    5      4  
4    8      5  
6    9      6  
')
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `eat` from my package [*safejoin*](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/safejoin), and "patch" the matches
from the rhs into the rhs when there is a column conflict.

```
# devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/safejoin")
library(safejoin)
library(dplyr)

eat(mydb, newdb, .by = "ID", .conflict = "patch")
#   ID    V1    V2 V3 V4
# 1  1 value value  0  0
# 2  2 value value  5  4
# 3  3 value value  0  0
# 4  4 value value  8  5
# 5  5 value value  0  0
# 6  6 value value  9  6
```

We can also coalesce the columns starting from the rhs, for the same effect :

```
eat(mydb, newdb, .by = "ID", .conflict = ~coalesce(.y,.x))
```